# Android studio Activity not open when i put following piece of code

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
    package com.appsoft23.bestmathtrainerforkids.free;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Add extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button startButton;
    ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int correctLocation;

    public void start(View view){

        startButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        TextView addTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addTextView);
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);


        Random rand = new Random();
        int h = rand.nextInt(21);
        int t = rand.nextInt(21);
        addTextView.setText(Integer.toString(h) + "+" + Integer.toString(t));
        correctLocation = rand.nextInt(4);
        int wrongAnswer;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            if (i == correctLocation){
                answers.add(h+t);
            } else {
                wrongAnswer = rand.nextInt(42);
                while (wrongAnswer == h+t){
                    wrongAnswer = rand.nextInt(42);
                }
                answers.add(wrongAnswer);
            }
        }
        button4.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(4)));
        button5.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(5)));
        button6.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(6)));
        button7.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(7)));

    }


}
```

it gives following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.appsoft23.bestmathtrainerforkids.free, PID: 3095
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appsoft23.bestmathtrainerforkids.free/com.appsoft23.bestmathtrainerforkids.free.Add}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
>                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
>                         at com.appsoft23.bestmathtrainerforkids.free.Add.onCreate(Add.java:53)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Please Help :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array list gives IndexOutOfBoundsException. Because arraylist only contails 4 element and you called it from 5 position.
Change it :

```
    button4.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
    button5.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
    button6.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
    button7.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

it trows exception because  your array size is 4 and you try to retrieve data from that position that doesn't exist in your array
try this

```
button4.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
button5.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
button6.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
button7.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are adding to arraylist using for loop for 4 times. so size is 4 and index would be 0,1,2,3.

for buttons you are setting text from arraylist using index 4,5,6,7

so the expection